# How to manipulate the list within a dictionary and add modify the values to create a new dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary which has index number as the key which ranges from 0 to 9 and the values of the dictionary is a list which contains 5 elements for index number 0 to 7 and 6 elements for index number 8 and 9.

- What I want to do is ignore the 0th element of each list from 0 to 7 and ignore the first two elements for indexes 8 and 9 (if they exist)
- Add 1000 to the first element of the modified list from index 0 to 7 and add 2500 to first element of the list for indexes 8 and 9 and modify the dictionary and use that dictionary for iterating in the dictionary and creating speeds dictionary as shown in the below example.

Can anyone please help to modify the test_dict achieve the same.

```
test_dict = {0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2:[7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3:[7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4:[7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6:[6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7:[7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8:[2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9:[2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

max_lst_len = max(len(lst) for lst in test_dict.items())

for i in range(max_lst_len):
    speeds={}
    for index in test_dict:
        try:
            speed = test_dict[index][i]
            speeds[index] = speed
        except IndexError:
            continue
```

Sorry if the question not shaped in the best form. I am really new here.
The expected modified dict that I am expecting is

```
{0: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1:[8000, 8800, 11000, 15000],.....,8:[5500, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9:[5500, 4800, 6000, 8500]
```

Comment: hi, welcome to SO! I suggest you edit your question and divide that BIG paragraph into bullet points. You can create them using '- ' at the beginning of a new line.

Comment: Thanks @miquelvir. I have added the points as bullet as suggested by you. can you please provide the solution if it's possible for you?

Comment: In the question you ask to skip the first two items in the 8-9 lists, but then in the requested output you show `9:[5500, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]`. Which do you need?

Comment: the provided expected output is basically wrong @Pietro

Comment: I have modified the expected output for index 8 and 9. Is something like possible?

Comment: Now the output is `9:[5500, 6000, 8500]`, so I'm guessing the `4800` was removed by mistake? Take a breath and check it calmly, there is no rush.

Comment: You now seem to want to ignore the first 3 items in the last 2 lists.

Comment: Edited again. Sorry for so many errors. Glad you guys are helping me out

Comment: No problem mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the specs I'm working with

- ignore the 0th element of each list from 0 to 7
- ignore the first two elements for lists 8 and 9
- add 1000 to the first element of the modified list for 0-7
- add 2500 for the first two elements of index 8 and 9 (per the comment to miquelvir)
- the lists could be empty
- modify `test_dict` in place

All together:

```
from pprint import pprint

test_dict = {
    0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    1: [7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    2: [7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    3: [7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    # 4: [7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    4: [],
    5: [7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    6: [6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    7: [7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000],
    # 8: [2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500],
    8: [],
    9: [2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500],
}

for k in test_dict:
    try:
        if k <= 7:
            test_dict[k] = test_dict[k][1:]
            test_dict[k][0] += 1000
        else:
            test_dict[k] = test_dict[k][2:]
            test_dict[k][0] += 2500
            test_dict[k][1] += 2500

    except IndexError as e:
        print(f"IndexError at {k}: {e}")

pprint(test_dict)
```

This code is very spread out, and is easily adapted to your needs.

Cheers!

Comment: Great breakdown of the problem @Pietro. But I didn't want this to be in speeds dict. I just want a modified test_dict.

Answer (score 0):

The provided solutions break and don't take intro consideration this request:

> (if they exist)

This does:

```
test_dict = {0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2:[7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3:[7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4:[7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6:[6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7:[7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8:[2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9:[2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

for idx, list_ in test_dict.items():
    if 0 <= idx <= 9:
        test_dict[idx] = list_[1:]
        try:
            for i in range(1 if idx <= 7 else 2):
                test_dict[idx][i] += 1000 if idx <= 7 else 2500
        except IndexError:
            pass

print(test_dict)
```

If you know the input size will be 10 for sure, we can further simplify it to:

```
test_dict = {0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2:[7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3:[7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4:[7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6:[6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7:[7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8:[2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9:[2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

for idx, list_ in test_dict.items():
    test_dict[idx] = list_[1:]
    try:
        for i in range(1 if idx <= 7 else 2):
            test_dict[idx][i] += 1000 if idx <= 7 else 2500
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(test_dict)
```

Notice also that your sample output does not ignore the first two elements but one, so this is what I've done. If we were to ignore the first two items as you mention:

```
test_dict = {0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2:[7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3:[7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4:[7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6:[6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7:[7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8:[2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9:[2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

for idx, list_ in test_dict.items():
    if 0 <= idx <= 9:
        test_dict[idx] = list_[1 if idx <= 7 else 2:]
        try:
            for i in range(1 if idx <= 7 else 2):
                test_dict[idx][i] += 1000 if idx <= 7 else 2500
        except IndexError:
            pass

print(test_dict)
```

If you know the input size will be 10 for sure, we can further simplify it to:

```
test_dict = {0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 1:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 2:[7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 3:[7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 4:[7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 5:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 6:[6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 7:[7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 8:[2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 9:[2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

for idx, list_ in test_dict.items():
    test_dict[idx] = list_[1 if idx <= 7 else 2:]
    try:
        for i in range(1 if idx <= 7 else 2):
            test_dict[idx][i] += 1000 if idx <= 7 else 2500
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(test_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @miquelvir. Can we add 2500 for the first two elements of index 8 and 9? I needed incremented values as it appears in the other indexes.

Comment: sure, done! mark as solved if this solves your question

Comment: I have modified the desired output, can you see if that's possible. Sorry for the repetition

Comment: it is wrong... notice that element 9 has length 6 and ends up with length 3... you have ignored 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you as the result doesn't match the expected result tha was posted.

However the expected result posted doesn't match the description in the post - it appears to be ignoring the 1st item in the last 2 lists not the first 2 items.

```py
test_dict = {0: [7110, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             1:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             2:[7080, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             3:[7620, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             4:[7050, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             5:[7590, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             6:[6990, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             7:[7400, 7000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
             8:[2760, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500], 
             9:[2730, 3000, 3800, 4800, 6000, 8500]}

speeds = {}

for ky in test_dict.keys():
    speeds[ky] = test_dict[ky][1:] if len(test_dict[ky]) == 5 else test_dict[ky][2:]
    speeds[ky][0] += 1000 if len(test_dict[ky]) == 5 else 2500
    
print(speeds)
```

### Result

```
{0: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 1: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 2: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 3: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 4: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 5: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 6: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 7: [8000, 8800, 11000, 15000], 
 8: [6300, 4800, 6000, 8500], 
 9: [6300, 4800, 6000, 8500]}
```